# Compile in 32 bit mode on 64 bit architecture

Tags: c

Just started moving Solaris C code to RedHat  Enterprise Linux 8.5.  The old Solaris code is 32 bit so I thought I would compile using 32 bit mode :

```
ksi_trunk]$ gcc -m32 ksi_rpt.c
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:452,
                 from /usr/include/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:27,
                 from ksi_rpt.c:19:
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:11: fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory
 # include <gnu/stubs-32.h>
```

Am I using the right 32 bit switch?

Comment: `No such file or directory` You did not install lib32 libraries for compilation.

Comment: On fedora, that file is in the development package for glibc, so the package is: `glibc-devel.i686`